# Plate Screw with load-bearing eye

Tags: tripod-heads, camera-straps, support-equipment

I love the idea of BlackRapid's replacement screw for the Manfrotto QR plate.
I tried to use the same screw to attach a Arca-Swiss plate, and it didn't work as the head is too wide to turn inside the recess under the plate profile.

Is there one that would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Peak Design make several Arca-Swiss compatible plates that can be used with a D-ring screw. So you could clip the BlackRapid strap onto that.

Look at their [ARCAplate](https://peakdesign.com/store/peakdesign.com/store/arcaplate), which includes the D-ring screw. Note that has now been replaced by the [PROplate](https://peakdesign.com/store/proplate), which doesn't have a D-ring as standard. But you can use it with the [Pro Drive Screw](https://peakdesign.com/store/pro-drive-screw), which has a D-ring.

Also see for more details about the D-ring: [Why is there no D-ring on the new PROplate?](http://support.peakdesign.com/hc/en-us/articles/203162105-Why-is-there-no-D-ring-on-the-new-PROplate-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a clamp which itself has a screw hole: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWes5KE3QZI